# Autolayout is not updating frames instantly in iOS8-Xcode6

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, xcode6

I'm using `autolayout` in `XCode6`.

I have applied the following constraints to a `scrollview`.

[image]

I have tried to access the frame of this scrollview in -`viewDidLoad` and -`viewWillAppear` methods for iPhone 4Inchs device. Here problem is, the scrollview's width is showing 600 in Log. But the width should be 300 in 4Ichs device as i'm using `autolayout`.
Seems `autolayout` will apply after some time interval. It is showing correct width in -`viewDidAppear` method as 300.

Is there any way to access the original frames in -`viewDidLoad` and -`viewWillAppear` methods ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no problem here. The width refers to the calculated width in Interface Builder not in the preview screen. Run it in a simulator or on a device. It will be fine as long as you set your constraints properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto layout doesn't give you the "right" frame sizes until a layout pass has happened. `viewDidLoad` is too early, and off the top of my head `willAppear` might be too. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is the right place.

Answer (score 2):

Place this code in your viewDidLoad()

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout();
self.view.layoutIfNeeded();
```

Before accessing `scorllView.frame.size.width`

Comment: Observed the frame of scorllView after the methods -setNeedsLayout, -layoutIfNeeded in -viewDidLoad, but it’s not delivering the final frame of scorllView. -viewDidLayoutSubviews is the solution i found. But getting the original frames in -viewDidLayoutSubviews and updating the UI based that is annoying. I wish there should be a better solution.

Comment: @AshokKumarS  I tried these two method today for getting updated frame for UITextField. I am getting the frame in viewWillAppear. and It is giving the right frames.

Comment: For some reason i'm not getting the original frames(But i tested it in a Share extension not in the main app). But it's okay, i'm using -viewDidLayoutSubviews method. If we add -setNeedsLayout, -layoutIfNeeded in -viewDidLoad or in -viewWillAppear explicitly, will it hit the performance(It's an extra cost even if it's a little)?

Answer (score 1):

From the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear its shows same as interface builder's dimensions. if you apps relay on scrollView frame(if you want them before viewDidAppear) call viewController instance `view` method before it presenting.

```
UIViewController *myVC = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[myVC view]
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC];
```

But this counting on apps performance.