# Autolayout: Incorrect frame sizes in ViewDidAppear

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a UIViewController for which I'm using Autolayout via IB to position and size its subviews.

For some reason I was not getting the correct UIView layout and I decided to log all the subview sizes in the VC.

I logged subview sizes in:

```
viewDidLoad{
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   print(uiview.size)
}

viewDidLayoutSubviews{
 print(uiview.size)
}
viewWillAppear{
 print(uiview.size)

}
viewDidAppear{
 print(uiview.size)
}
```

the subview sizes are correct in :

1. viewDidLoad
2. viewDidLayoutSubviews
3. viewWillAppear
4. viewDidLayoutSubviews

but it becomes incorrect in:

5. viewDidLayoutSubviews
6. viewDidAppear

How can I use correct subview sizes from the ViewWillAppear? And why are my sizes incorrect in the final viewDidLayoutSubviews call and in viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own question.

I constrain views proportional to VC's height.

The VC that I'm displaying has a Navigation Bar. All the view sizes are correct,(even in viewDidLoad because I call layoutIfNeeded()), until the VC starts drawing the Navigation Bar and shrinks the Superview's height; thus, shrinking its subview's heights.

All I have to do is to Extend edges under the top bar by ticking the appropriate box in the VC's Attributes Inspector. This way VC will not shrink the superview of my subviews.

Answer (score 5):

Your "correct sizes" are from before AutoLayout has done its work. The frames will be the frames from the Interface Builder document. You need to fix your constraints to achieve whatever frames you are expecting.

AutoLayout hasn't completed until after the final viewDidLayoutSubviews call just before viewDidAppear.

Comment: If thats the case then how does the autolayout reach the correct frame sizes until it reaches viewDidAppear. Additionally, my constraints are correct Im 100% sure.

Comment: The final viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewDidAppear are the only correct places to see AutoLayout's finished frames. viewWillAppear is too early. Check the console and make sure there are no constraints breaking.

Comment: Here's a previous answer for you to reference about viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275116/autolayout-is-not-updating-frames-instantly-in-ios8-xcode6

Comment: @bjtitus, how do I know if it is the final viewDidLayoutSubviews before viewDidAppear?